# How to display text in contains in certain cell number at different sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, list

I have a list of number in Sheet A and I want to call and display the list of text (ENTIRE ROW) that represent by the same list of number in sheet B.

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

In *Sheet A*, cell **B1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet B'!A1:B11,2,FALSE)
```

and copy downward.

*Sheet A*:

[image]

If *Sheet B* is like:

[image]

As you see the numbers in *Sheet A* don't have to be in order.

Adjust worksheet names and range limits to match your actual data.

Once this is complete, you can use similar *VLOOKUP()* formulas to capture any other columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

*You can try combination of Index and Match functions.*

Write this formula in **Cell B2 of Sheet A**:

```
=INDEX(SheetB!$A$2:$B$20,MATCH(A2,SheetB!$A$2:$A$20,0),2)
```

**N.B.**

- Fill this formula downwards.
- please adjust the Cell address as per you need.